# In windows 10 how do I allow users to set up windows hello fingerprint?

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure, microsoft-intune

I have a windows organization for which I'm the administrator. The users are registered to an Azure active directory which is managed with Intune.

When I set up the computer I first sign in with my windows admin account. Then I add the the user's account as a normal user.

When my users try to set up fingerprint or picture sign in, they are getting the alert in the image below.

How do I allow the users to set up windows hello fingerprint and picture on their computer?

[image: This setting is managed by your organization. Contact your admin for more info.]

Comment: Have you setup an Identity Protection Profile in Intune?  Start there at least...checking the MS Docs for this and ensuring you have a test profile and device to test the policy against.

Comment: I don;t think I have that yet. I'll research starting from there.